Не работают постоянные ссылки в wordpress
По какой то причине не работают постоянные ссылки кроме "простые". Если выставить другой тип то при входе на страницу пишет ошибку 404. Сервер на Nginx
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

           location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


           location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

            location = /favicon.ico {
                         log_not_found off;
                         access_log off;
            }

            location = /robots.txt {
                         allow all;
                         log_not_found off;
                         access_log off;
           }
       
            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                         expires 30d;
                         log_not_found off;
             add_header Cache-Control "public";
           }

}

Может быть дело в конфигурации?

Или сайт не там или после изменения конфига не перезапустил сервер.

Помогло вписывание пути /wordpress/ в эту часть конфига
location /wordpress/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}

